# What is the big-O of this program where nested loops depend on each other?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Can't figure out what the big O for this block of code is. Outer loop is log(n), but how bout inner loop that depends on outer loop?

```
for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i = i * 3) {
    for (int j = i; j < A.length; j++) {
        // Simple computation
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is it supposed to be `int i = 1` or `i = i + 3`?

Comment: Sorry my bad it is `i = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A.Length == n`, the inner loop runs in `n-i` each time. Hence, the total complextiy of the program is `sum(n - i)` for `i = 1, 3, 9, ..., n = 3^log_3(n)`. As the number of `i` is `log_3(n)`, the complexity is `T(n) = n * log_3(n) - (3^(log_3(n)+1)-1) = n * log_3(n) - 3(n-1) = O(nlog(n))`

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As is your code will not complete because `i = i * 3` means that `i` will always be `0`.

From your comment it is supposed to be `i = 1`. So, on each iteration of the outer loop, the problem size is reduced by a constant factor of 3. This means that the outer loop takes `O(log n)` steps.

The inner loop takes `O(n)` in the worst case and is run `O(log n)` times. Therefore, the entire running time is `O(n log n)`.

Be sure to check your post for typos and do some research in the future :).

Comment: For the full analysis, see OmG, but we arrive at the same result.